# progress bar for multiple ajax jsonp processes

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, jsonp

My web app requests information from several different web servers via jsonp ajax requests. Some complete immediately while others take longer. I would like to show a little whirly animation in a div until all requests complete. Of course, jQuery's `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxComplete()` don't work with jsonp. What can I do?

**update**: turns out, the "beforeSend" and "complete" options of the `$.ajax` work just fine. Problem solved.

Comment: can you please post your own answer and close the question so ?

Answer (score 0):

In my JavaScript, I added the `beforeSend` and `complete` options:

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "path/to/web/server",
    "data": data,
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "beforeSend": function() {
        $('#loading').show();
    },
    "complete": function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
    },
    "success": function(data) {

        ..
    }
});
```

and, in my html, a div with the loading image

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

The above works well.